# What is the best way to deal with local DEB packages (i.e. ones not installed from repos)?

Tags: apt, repository, localrepository

I just want a "guru's opinion" on the best way to deal with those pesky little "singleton" debs that you don't get out of any APT repo. For example google-chrome (I know they finally made a repo), virtualbox, and unstable WINE. I'm actually using debian testing (wheezy) now, and I particularly miss wine and emerald. I've had a lot of experience doing things the hard way then finding out about some really elegant trick that solves all problems. I'm wondering if there is one for this. The closest thing I could find is http://linuxwave.blogspot.com/2009/04/adding-local-directory-to-apt.html . This is pretty good, but us it as good as it gets? I'm considering eventually writing a shell/perl script that checks each package's website for updates and downloads it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, APT repositories are the elegant solution. If a distributor does not have an APT repository, yes, you will need to script fetching each package and generate the packages.gz file for the local directory repository. The biggest issue is fetching the package - since there's no repo, there's no standard and scripting will be very specific for each package.